# AVSpeechSynthesis ended

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, avspeechsynthesizer

Hi I'm building an iOS 7 app using AVSpeechSynthesizer and AVSpeechUtterance I'm trying to figure out when the synthesis is done. To be more specific I'd love to change the appereance of the play/pause button when the synthesis is over.
Someone can help me understand if there is some method called at the end of the synthesis?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `delegate` property of `AVSpeechSynthesizer` and implement the following delegate method:

```
- (void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didFinishSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance {
    //do whatever you need to do
}
```

You may also be interested in `speechSynthesizer:didCancelSpeechUtterance:` delegate method if you stop speaking programatically (for example, after a button is pressed).